# "and" vs "or" for matching two attributes

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I often say "I want this code to work in Python 2 **or** Python 3".  I often wonder if I should use "and" instead of "or".  Would "I want this code to work in Python 2 **and** Python 3" be better?  Both forms sound good in usage.  Is there a name for this kind of conjunction where both forms seem OK?

Comment: Your original (using *or*) allows the code to work in Python 3 but not Python 2, and still fulfil your requirement. Using *and* requires it to work in both versions of Python.

Comment: What about using **both** instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conjunction *and* is much, much better. It implies that you want your code to work in **both** Python 2 **and** Python 3. Using *or* implies that you don't care if your code doesn't work with both. Even worse, some people (like me) might incorrectly assume that you  want your code to work in **either** Python 2 **or** Python 3.

+1 for using Python.

Comment: In the OP's wording, the *or* version doesn't prohibit the code from working in both.

Comment: You're right. I suppose that I made that assumption because he didn't use *and*.

Comment: Nicely explained, I totally agree here.